# Client verification in openfire via sms

Tags: android, sms, xmpp, openfire

I have created XMPP client in android and i am using openfire server. Now I want to verify user mobile number. after a lot of search i could not figure it out how to done it, if anyone know please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multi platform mobile number verification.

I am using it on android.

500 free verification's per day

https://www.cognalys.com/